# Version Control

Tags: version-control

Framework: Genesis

Child Theme: Genesis Sample

I am hoping to soon begin making changes to my CSS, in order to alter the appearance of my website. I have read that this is a terrible idea if you are not using version control. I am only wanting to do development for my own sites, so my aim is to learn as much as possible about CSS/HTML as I can, and then begin making alterations. So far, the version control methodologies I've seen are extremely complex, and suitable only for someone who is neck deep in the webdev field. Any suggestions for a simple version control system that is easy to setup?

Comment: for small project (subjective definition, but yours sounds like one) it is good enough to just keep organized backups.

Comment: Have a look at git, your typically only using 3-5 commands even on complex projects, there are GUI's that can help you understand it better.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. When you say organized backups, do you mean of each change made, i.e. copy paste code into a text doc., save as "code change 1" and then do this each time you change something? Also, would it be important to backup every part of my site?

Comment: For a simple site, the version control *is* your backup. (But you'd better have backups for the files of the version control system!)

Comment: The granularity of commits is up to you. It makes sense to commit units that you want to be able to back out. So if you change all backgrounds to yellow and all foregrounds to blue, those two changes together might make more sense as one commit, rather than each in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used **Source Safe, Subversion, Mercurial, Git, and TFVC**. from that list I found Subversion to be the easiest to use. Second in the list is Mercurial which is supported by BitBucket. TFVC reminds me a lot of Source Safe -- which I do not recommend -- and I found Git to be somewhat similar to Mercurial. I always recommend creating a **BitBucket, GitHub, or Visual Studio Online** account for backing up your version control. If you go with Subversion I recommend backing up your repository online using either **OneDrive, DropBox, or any other online storage services.**